# Kali boot USB drive not showing up in boot menu

Tags: usb, startup

I am trying to boot Kali Linux from my late 2020 M1 MacBook Air with macOS Monterey.
I tried to boot an x64 Kali image on an M1 system, but encountered the following problem.

I used both Balena Etcher and Terminal to create my bootable USB drive and both showed success. So, I shut down my computer and press the power button until the boot menu appears.

At this point, I am getting the options: Macintosh HD, Options with the symbol of settings, but no USB drive that I named Kali. After that, I press on the Macintosh HD, because I do not want to recover my Mac. When my computer opens and immediately displays a popup shows with the warning/error message "The disk you attached was not readable by this computer".

Any ideas what the problem is and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the name of the file you downloaded from Kali?

Comment: So, from looking at your answer, you tried to boot an x64 Kali image on an M1 system? Might have helped to mention that in the question :-)

Comment: Yes, that's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for [information](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253736285) on the Apple Discussions site, and I received this answer:

> Kali on the Apple M1
>
> As we announced in [Kali 2021.1](https://www.kali.org/blog/kali-linux-2021-1-release) we supported installing **Kali Linux on
> Parallels** on Apple Silicon Macs, **well with 2021.4, we now also support
> it on the [VMware Fusion Public Tech Preview](https://blogs.vmware.com/teamfusion/2021/09/fusion-for-m1-public-tech-preview-now-available.html)** thanks to the [5.14 kernel](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/linux)
> having the modules needed for the virtual GPU used. We also have
> updated the open-vm-tools [package](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/open-vm-tools), and [Kali’s installer](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/debian-installer) will
> automatically detect if you are installing under VMware and install
> the open-vm-tools-desktoppackage, which should allow you to change the
> resolution out of the box. As a reminder, this is still a *preview* from
> VMware, so there may be some rough edges. There is no extra
> [documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/virtualization/install-vmware-guest-vm/) for this because the [installation process](https://www.kali.org/docs/installation/hard-disk-install/) is the same as
> VMWare on 64-bit and 32-bit Intel systems, just using the [arm64 ISO](https://www.kali.org/get-kali/).
> **As a reminder, virtual machines on Apple Silicon are still limited to
> arm64 architecture only.**

So, I gave up running it from the USB drive, after I tried several USB drives, and ran it on VMware.