# How can I merge the free space with Apple_APFS Container disk3

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, partition

I searched before posting this and did find a couple of similar questions. However, they are not same as my situation.
I had resized the partition Apple_APFS Container disk3 on disk0s2 to free up some space to install Kali but learnt later that I can't dual boot on my MacBook M1. How can I merge the (free space) with 94.4 GB to Apple_APFS Container disk3 on disk0s2 in the screenshot below? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Please add Terminal output as text, not as an image.

Comment: Sure! This is my first question here. I will keep that in mind. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is given below.

```
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
```

The following was taken from the man page for the `diskutil` command.

> You can specify a size of zero (0) to grow the targeted APFS Physical Store such that all remaining space is filled to the next partition or the end of the partition map.

---

Note: Kali's [instructions](https://www.kali.org/docs/installation/hard-disk-install-on-mac/) do not actually state Kali can not be installing on an M1 Mac. There is also [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/438241/kali-boot-usb-drive-not-showing-up-in-boot-menu/438443#438443), which addresses running Kali by using Parallels or VMware Fusion.

Comment: Thank you so much David! It worked for me! :-) Could you please explain what that 0 at the end means in the command? I will check the links you provided. However, I didn't want to run Kali from within a VM. Hence I was trying to dual boot using rEFInd.