# Merging free space back with main partition

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partition, memory

[image]

I created a partition for Linux that I do not need anymore. I deleted that partition and now am left with this free space. Am I able to merge this back into my main storage?

```
diskutil list disk0
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:             Apple_APFS_ISC Container disk1         524.3 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         398.0 GB   disk0s2
                    (free space)                         96.4 GB    -
   3:        Apple_APFS_Recovery Container disk2         5.4 GB     disk0s4
```

Comment: Have you tried the command `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0`?

Comment: @DavidAnderson that worked! Thank you.

Comment: Good to read the command worked. I believe your question has been asked before. If I (or someone else) finds the appropriate previous question, then your question will probably be flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How can I merge the free space with Apple\_APFS Container disk3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/438653/how-can-i-merge-the-free-space-with-apple-apfs-container-disk3).